# How many instances of class A does the following code create?

Tags: java, oop

How many instances of class A does the following code create ??

```
A x, u, v;
x=new A();
A y=x;
A z=new A();
```

Comment: Just two. Everytime `new A()` is called.

Comment: this is YOUR homework

Comment: You could easily have tested this by adding a log statement to the parameterless constructor and checking how many times the statement is logged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A x, u, v;              // creating x,u,v reference variable of type A
x=new A();              // creating a new instance of class A and assigning it to reference variable x
A y=x;                  // assigning the instance x to another reference variable y of same type A
A z=new A();            // creating another instance of A and assigning to reference variable z
```

Therefore, only **two** instances of `class A` are created.

Answer (score 1):

Two. Only on the new statements.

Answer (score 0):

I see two, one for each `new A()`

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use the `new` operator. Referring to an object that is already created, does *not* create a new instance.

Take a look at the **Java tutorial** for creating objects, it explains everything nicely: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use the `new` operator, an object is created in heap memory. So in this case two objects will be created.